# Is there any direction toward supporting a direct post payment processor model

Tags: payment-processor

I was reading Eileen's blog here:
https://civicrm.org/blogs/eileen/rethinking-payment-processing

and was wondering if there is any plans to update the payment processor architecture to support the direct post model.

All data is collected on a civi form in the browser but the form is posted directly to the payment processor. The user is redirected to a url in civi that then provides success or failure processing.

It seems that the doTransferCheckout() method still doesn't quite handle this approach.

Thanks

Comment: This works for processors that are integrated into the https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor extension with a JS submit. Probably in the longer term I would see the use of JS to pre-submit seems to be becoming more prominent.